# Specify version for yum in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I recently tried to run stack based amazon cloud formation template for WordPress. Unfortunately yum installs old PHP and I got this communicate:

> Your server is running PHP version 5.3.29 but WordPress 5.2.1 requires at least 5.6.20.

I change the stack and specify version:

```
     "install_wordpress" : {
        "packages" : {
          "yum" : {
            "php"          : ["5.6.20"],
            "php-mysql"    : [],
            "mysql"        : [],
            "mysql-server" : [],
            "mysql-devel"  : [],
            "mysql-libs"   : [],
            "httpd"        : []
          }
        },
```

But still I got same error. How to properly specify version for yum in cloud formation template?

As base template I used default template provided by AWS:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/WordPress_Single_Instance.template

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @shrewmouse Amazon Linux AMI as defined in default WordPress template. I edited question and added link to template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `ami-0080e4c5bc078760e` which is for [Amazon Linux 2018.03](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018.03-release-notes/). According to the [package list](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/) PHP 5.3 is the latest version available there. You can switch AMI to Ubuntu 16.04 which includes [PHP 7.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php) or Ubuntu 18.04 with [PHP 7.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php). You can also manually install a newer version of PHP from source.

Another option is enabling `amazon-linux-extras`. You need to enable the PHP 7.2 topic before calling `cfn-init` which will install the packages listed in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`. You can also use two config sets. See [this example](https://cloudonaut.io/migrating-to-amazon-linux-2/).

Basically:

```
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
      "configSets": {
        "default": ["extras", "config"]
      },
      "extras": {
        "commands": {
          "0_enable_php": {
            "command": "amazon-linux-extras enable php7.2",
            "test": "[ ! grep -Fxq '[amzn2extra-php7.2]' /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-extras.repo ]"
         }
      }
      "config": {
        "packages": {
          "yum": {
            "php"          : [],
            "php-mysql"    : [],
            "mysql"        : [],
            "mysql-server" : [],
            "mysql-devel"  : [],
            "mysql-libs"   : [],
            "httpd"        : []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is the point. I don't want install anything manually since I'm using Cloud Front template. Also I cannot easily change Amazon AMI to Ubuntu because each distro uses different package managers.

Comment: You can run arbitrary scripts from CloudFormation too, not just yum.